# How to printf %d literally

Tags: c, printf

#### How to printf %d literally

It's probably a simple answer. But I can't seem to find the answer.

Let's say I want to:

```
printf( "printf(\"%d\", x );" );
```

I want the output to literally be: `printf( "%d", x );`

Is there a way to do it? If I just put in the code that I wrote above, a number gets placed into %d, but I don't want anything placed in there. I just want the literal %d.

Comment: [Read the documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) (or another version, as appropriate). It will explain how the format string works: i.e. how do you know that "%d" does what it does anyway?

Comment: This is what I call metaprogramming.

Comment: @H2CO3 Touché. Previous comment retracted >:}

Comment: @pst So now I had to delete mine as well, and both of us look like a proper idiot. (JK)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escape the `%` with another `%`:

```
printf( "printf(\"%%d\", x );" );
```

Answer (score 5):

Well why don't we exercise some truly safe programming practice around here?

```
printf("%s", "printf(\"%d\", x );" );
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `%%` for a literal percent.

Answer (score 3):

Use `puts` or `fputs`, these are the choice to output unformated text

```
puts( "printf(\"%d\", x );");
```

to have it together with a trailing newline (which I find a good idea) or

```
fputs( "printf(\"%d\", x );", stdout);
```

if you insist in not having a newline.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `puts` and `fputs` since there is no formatting being done. Also, I believe `fputs` is a bit more efficient is it not?

Comment: @KeithMiller, unless you are pumping really a lot of text to a stream (in a compiler e.g) there should not be much performance difference. The output speed should mainly depend on the speed of the output device. The energy efficiency might be a bit better, though, burning a bit less C02 to heat your CPU :)

Answer (score 1):

Double the `%` to "escape" it:

```
printf( "printf(\"%%d\", x );" );
                   ^--
```